# how to access and open files in folder automatically and check similarity with input file in python

Tags: python, nlp

i am making a desktop tool for plagiarism checking between documents. I use stopwords, vectorizer tf-idf etc and use cosine similarity to check similarity between two documents

```
{import nltk, string
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from  nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 
import nltk

userinput1  = input ("Enter file name:")
myfile1 = open(userinput1).read()
stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
word1 = nltk.word_tokenize(myfile1)
filtration_sentence = []
for w in word1:
    word = word_tokenize(myfile1)
    filtered_sentence = [w for w in word if not w in stop_words]
    print(filtered_sentence)

userinput2  = input ("Enter file name:")
myfile2 = open(userinput2).read()
stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
word2 = nltk.word_tokenize(myfile2)
filtration_sentence = []
for w in word2:
    word = word_tokenize(myfile2)
    filtered_sentence = [w for w in word if not w in stop_words]
    print(filtered_sentence)

stemmer = nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer()
remove_punctuation_map = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation)

def stem_tokens(tokens):
    return [stemmer.stem(item) for item in tokens]

'''remove punctuation, lowercase, stem'''
def normalize(text):
    return stem_tokens(nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower().translate(remove_punctuation_map)))
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=normalize, stop_words='english')

def cosine_sim(myfile1, myfile2):
    tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform([myfile1, myfile2])
    return ((tfidf * tfidf.T).A)[0,1]
print(cosine_sim(myfile1,myfile2))}
```

but the problem is "i have to check similarity of input file from user with the number of files in folder. i tried my best to access folder ,open files automatically but not succeed. "anyone here who can tell me how to access folder containing files and open files one by one and compare with input file.i am using python 3.4.4 and window 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you need to get all the files present in a directory/ folder

```
import os
fileList = os.listdir('path_to_the_directory')
for eachFile in fileList:
    with open(eachFile, 'rb') as _fp:
        fileData = _fp.read()
        print("FILE DATA (%s):\n\n%s\n\n"%(_fp.name, fileData))
```

This will iterate through all the file in a directory and call the function doSomething on the file pointer

Comment: @Muhammad instead of passing the file pointer pass the _fb.read()

Comment: Error in output .. i can't understand what is error                       Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/umer/Desktop/stack.py", line 11, in <module>
    word1 = nltk.word_tokenize(_fb)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 109, in word_tokenize
    return [token for sent in sent_tokenize(text, language)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 94, in sent_tokenize
    return tokenizer.tokenize(text)

Comment: use
`word1 = nltk.word_tokenize(fb.read())`
instead of
`word1 = nltk.word_tokenize(fb)`

Comment: just guide me how to open number of files in folder and print all files data

Comment: @Muhammad I've edited my answer, please do mark it as answer if its satisfying your need

Comment: it will open files but in case of pdf file ,it should open pdf file correctly by displaying text as in the pdf file but not. any solution or help me to sort out this @Soumesh Banerjee

Comment: @Muhammad PDF have some encoding and you need to use some 3rd part library like [this](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html) to extract text from pdf